# Generator for union of two sets of keys for named arguments with Clojure Spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Lets look at the example given in the Clojure Spec [Guide](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_entity_maps) for `clojure.spec/merge`

```
(require '[clojure.spec     :as spec]
         '[clojure.spec.gen :as gen])

(spec/def :animal/kind string?)
(spec/def :animal/says string?)
(spec/def :animal/common (spec/keys :req [:animal/kind :animal/says]))
(spec/def :dog/tail? boolean?)
(spec/def :dog/breed string?)
(spec/def :animal/dog (spec/merge :animal/common
                                  (spec/keys :req [:dog/tail? :dog/breed])))
```

From this spec we can both generate data and in turn validate it:

```
(gen/generate (spec/gen :animal/dog))
=> {:animal/kind "bB", :animal/says "z9C0T465Q8OPXn5dUB8Wqk8K5Jnn",
    :dog/tail? false, :dog/breed "B2MLQnj"}

(spec/valid? :animal/dog
             {:animal/kind "bB", :animal/says "z9C0T465Q8OPXn5dUB8Wqk8K5Jnn",
              :dog/tail? false, :dog/breed "B2MLQnj"})
=> true
```

But if we were to slightly modify the spec so that it was for a sequence of named arguments instead of a map, like

```
(spec/def :animal/common (spec/keys* :req [:animal/kind :animal/says]))
(spec/def :animal/dog (spec/merge :animal/common
                                  (spec/keys* :req [:dog/tail? :dog/breed])))
```

, we can still validate data against the spec:

```
(spec/valid? :animal/dog
             '(:animal/kind "dog"
               :animal/says "woof"
               :dog/tail?   true
               :dog/breed   "retriever"))
=> true
```

But we do lose the ability to generate data:

```
(gen/generate (spec/gen :animal/dog))

; 1. Unhandled clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
;    Couldn't satisfy such-that predicate after 100 tries.
```

Is this an error on my side, an implementation error in spec, or just the way `clojure.spec/merge` is intended to work? Can we work around this by attaching a generator?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of spec/merge, it seems that there's a special case in there for generating maps, but not for generating sequences of key/value pairs. I'd guess this is because it's still alpha, and not even API stable yet, let alone fully implemented. Supplying your own generator seems to do the trick though. For example:

```
(gen/generate (spec/gen :animal/dog {:animal/dog #(clojure.test.check.generators/return '(:animal/kind "2qAW61r3030B", :animal/says "7k", :dog/tail? true, :dog/breed "00Y8C9T25cRrSQsnjOn26a"))}))
```